# View not loading when Model is passed to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a JQuery Mobile app that I'm trying to create a View that populates a drop down list.  I create an IEnumerable list of the model, in the controller and then pass it to the view.  The view never renders and just says "Error Loading Page" (from J-Query I presume).  I even put a breakpoint at the top of the view on the Layout= line and it doesn't reach there.

Here's my Controller:

```
    public virtual ActionResult List()
    {
        string customerCode = RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();

        var csdDB = new DBContext(customerCode);

        // Return all locations
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> sites = csdDB.Sites
                              .OrderBy(o => o.SiteName)
                              .AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Text = s.SiteName,
                                  Value = s.SiteID.ToString()
                              });

        return View(sites);
    }
```

Here's the view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Site";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@model IEnumerable<Models.Site>

<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
            Locations
        </li>
        @foreach(var site in Model)
        { 
        <li data-theme="c">
            <a href="~/Site/SiteMenu/@site.SiteID" data-transition="slide">
                @site.SiteName - (@site.ICAO)
            </a>
        </li>
       }
    </ul>
</div>
```

This page gets called from a previous page, like so:

```
            <li data-theme="c">
            @Html.ActionLink("Sites by HTML.ActionLink", "List", "Site", new { id = @ViewBag.CustomerCode }, new
            {

                data_native_menu = "false",
                name = "",
                data_theme = "c"
            })
        </li>
```

DBContext was created using Entity Framework, btw.  I also checked to be sure that the list "sites" is getting populated, and it is.

Any ideas as to why the View isn't loading?

Comment: What do you see in Firebug/dev tools/Fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you define your model as:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Site>
```

But in your controller you return

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> sites = ...
return View(sites);
```

But `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is not `IEnumerable<Models.Site>` so it throws an exception and you get the error from Jquery Mobile.

To solve it you need to return `IEnumerable<Models.Site>` from your action. Just remove to whole `Select` part and it should work:

```
IEnumerable<Site> sites = csdDB.Sites
                          .OrderBy(o => o.SiteName)
                          .AsEnumerable();
return View(sites);
```

Anyway it made no sense to convert the sites into `SelectListItem` because in your views you used properties like `SiteName` and `ICAO` form your model. Maybe it was a copy-paste error...